# Compare two lists' indexes values and write NOT similar values to another list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

Consider these lists:

```
list_one = ['0414870590', '3965667115', '7686006277', '0736885667', '2580894453', '4890895590']
```

and

```
list_two = [['1', 'acppkbgrfi', '1', '0414870590', 'foo', 'bar'], 
['2', 'zhwgvdwoif', '1', '8201315776', 'foo', 'bar'], 
['3', 'jbimbttwmo', '1', '4366752905', 'foo', 'bar'], 
['4', 'dalroxsqxt', '1', '0652459418', 'foo', 'bar'], 
['5', 'jbygszsfcw', '1', '1876053449', 'foo', 'bar'], 
['6', 'hcbrgydtxx', '1', '1138310041', 'foo', 'bar'], 
['7', 'rlkadtqarj', '1', '7479978778', 'foo', 'bar'], 
['8', 'koafneqxgh', '1', '0539402828', 'foo', 'bar'], 
['9', 'lsaakfoqdf', '1', '0300592696', 'foo', 'bar']]
```

I want to find only these entries where entry in `list_one` are NOT equal with `list_two[j][3]`.
Here's what I thought would work, since it seems so logical, but seems like it's flawed.

```
list_only_not_similar = []

for i in list_one:
    for j in list_two:
        if i != j[3]:
            list_only_not_similar.append(j)
```

If I had everything right and since there's only one match (`list_one[0]` -> `'0414870590'` and
`list_two[0][3]` -> `'0414870590'`), meaning that `list_only_not_similar` array's length would be `8`.
But it's `53`:

```
>>> len(list_only_not_similar)
53
```

So my desired output in the list_only_not_similar would be:

```
[['2', 'zhwgvdwoif', '1', '8201315776', 'foo', 'bar'], 
['3', 'jbimbttwmo', '1', '4366752905', 'foo', 'bar'], 
['4', 'dalroxsqxt', '1', '0652459418', 'foo', 'bar'], 
['5', 'jbygszsfcw', '1', '1876053449', 'foo', 'bar'], 
['6', 'hcbrgydtxx', '1', '1138310041', 'foo', 'bar'], 
['7', 'rlkadtqarj', '1', '7479978778', 'foo', 'bar'], 
['8', 'koafneqxgh', '1', '0539402828', 'foo', 'bar'], 
['9', 'lsaakfoqdf', '1', '0300592696', 'foo', 'bar']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because for each value in `list_two` you're adding the value from `list_one` if it's not equal to the value found at `list_two[j][3]`.

You could adapt your current solution by counting the number of occurrences of each value in `list_only_not_similar`,  and comparing that to the length of `list_two`. Anything with an equal length is not found in any element.

But that's terrible, **do not do that**.

### How to solve a problem

#### Write it in English

I find the best way to figure out how to get what I want is to write down what I would explain to someone:

> I want all of the values from `list_two` where the third value is not found in `list_one`

From there, it's not much of a stretch to translate that to Python:

```
values_i_want= []
for value in list_two:
    if not value[3] in list_one:
        values_i_want.append(value)
```

#### Optimize

However, depending on the number of values in `list_one` and `list_two` you may find that this takes a *long* time. That's because in Python comparisons are *expensive*, and if the value is not in `list_one` you're going to be performing `N*N` (or `O(N`<sup>`2`</sup>`)`) comparisons. That's a lot.

You can drastically reduce the number of comparisons by changing `list_one` into a set:

```
set_one = set(list_one)
```

Because sets are based on hash values, you've changed the lookup to constant time for every value, so instead of `N*N` comparisons you're looking at `N*1`.

#### Simplify(Refactor)

Now, once you have this code doing what you want, you can simplify by turning it into a list comprehension, as Hackaholic did:

```
values_I_want = [value for value in list_two if list_two[3] not in set_one]
```

Of course, `values_I_want` isn't the best variable name, so you can do:

```
list_not_similar = [x for x in list_two if x[3] not in set_one]
```

As you develop more familiarity with the language and programming, for small problems like this frequently you can jump straight from hearing the problem into writing the final code, but don't worry too much about being able to do that *now*.

Comment: Although every answer works, I really appreciate the time you took to write this.

Answer (score 3):

```
[sublist for sublist in list_two if sublist[3] not in list_one]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should exchange loops places and check every j element against each i element and add it to the resulting list only if none of the i elements were the same as the field you are interested in.

```
list_only_not_similar = []
for j in list_two:
    f = True
    for i in list_one:
        if i == j[3]:
            f = False
            break
    if f:
        list_only_not_similar.append(j)
```

The fact is that you were adding every suitable j element for every i element, but you should've checked every j element against each i element and only add it to the resulting list if all of the i elements are checked. Also a break is there because if you found at least one element that equal - you don't have to check others - the line is out of result anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over list_one because simple IN statement should be enough:

```
list_one = ['0414870590', '3965667115', '7686006277', '0736885667', '2580894453', '4890895590']

list_two = [['1', 'acppkbgrfi', '1', '0414870590', 'foo', 'bar'],
            ['2', 'zhwgvdwoif', '1', '8201315776', 'foo', 'bar'],
            ['3', 'jbimbttwmo', '1', '4366752905', 'foo', 'bar'],
            ['4', 'dalroxsqxt', '1', '0652459418', 'foo', 'bar'],
            ['5', 'jbygszsfcw', '1', '1876053449', 'foo', 'bar'],
            ['6', 'hcbrgydtxx', '1', '1138310041', 'foo', 'bar'],
            ['7', 'rlkadtqarj', '1', '7479978778', 'foo', 'bar'],
            ['8', 'koafneqxgh', '1', '0539402828', 'foo', 'bar'],
            ['9', 'lsaakfoqdf', '1', '0300592696', 'foo', 'bar']]

list_only_not_similar = []

# make a set from list for performance purpose
set_one = set(list_one)

for j in list_two:
    if j[3] not in set_one:
        list_only_not_similar.append(j)

print len(list_only_not_similar)
```

And output will be:

```
8
```